# Second derivative of local parametrisation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

I'm having a hard time with the product rule here. I keep making mistakes. This is what I have: $$\boldsymbol{\alpha}(t) = \boldsymbol{x}(u(t), v(t)) \implies \boldsymbol{\alpha} ' = u'(t)\cdot \boldsymbol{x}_u(u(t), v(t)) + v'(t)\cdot \boldsymbol{x}_v (u(t), v(t)).$$

How would I write $\boldsymbol{\alpha}''(t)$? This is the second derivative of a curve on a surface in diff geom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\alpha' = u'\frac{dx}{du} + v'\frac{dx}{dv}$

$\alpha'' = u''\frac{dx}{du} + u'(u'\frac{dx^2}{du^2} + v'\frac{dx^2}{dudv}) + v''\frac{dx}{dv} + v'(u'\frac{dx^2}{dvdu} + v'\frac{dx^2}{dv^2}) = u''\frac{dx}{du} + v''\frac{dx}{dv} + (u')^2\frac{d^2x}{du^2} + (v')^2\frac{d^2x}{dv^2} + 2u'v'\frac{dx^2}{dudv}$